# How do I efficiently perform the same function across multiple groups of columns in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am cleaning a csv for data analysis and I'm new to python, so I am trying my best to make this as straightforward as possible in case anyone wants to go back into this later.

I want to perform a straightforward operation on four columns and add a new column with the result, then efficiently repeat that for 10 other sets of columns.

My dataframe looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A1' : [10, 20, 30, 10], 
'A2' : [10,20,30,40],
'A3' : [30, 0, 40, 10],
'A4' : [75, 0, 0, 25],
'B1' : [10, 20, 30, 40],
'B2' : [30, 0, 20, 40],
'B3' : [10, 10, 20, 30],
'B4' : [40, 30, 20, 10]})

#     A1   A2   A3   A4   B1   B2   B3   B4  
#     10   10   30   75   10   30   10   40
#     20   20    0    0   20    0   10   30
#     30   30   40    0   30   20   20   20
#     10   40   10   25   40   40   30   10
```

I want to create a new column (A_dif) with the value of (A1+A2+A3)-A4. I've able to do that as follows:

```
df['A_dif'] = df.loc[:, A1:A3].sum(numeric_only=True, axis=1) - df.loc[:,'A4']
```

However, I need to do that for the B columns (and about 10 similar groups of columns). I can do that manually, but I would like an efficient function that accomplishes this. I tried to create following function (and then make a loop with it) but can't get it to work:

```
def difference(df, a: str, b: str, c: str) :
     df.loc[:, a:b].sum(numeric_only=True, axis=1) - df.loc[:,c]

test = difference(df, 'A1', 'A3', 'A4')
print(test)
# returns None
```

Thank you for any help you can offer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group columns by a suffix (here the first letter of column name) and compute your function:

```
def difference(df):
   return df.iloc[:, :3].sum(numeric_only=True, axis=1) - (df.iloc[:, 3])

df1 = df.groupby(df.columns.str[0], axis=1).apply(difference).add_suffix('_diff')
out = pd.concat([df, df1], axis=1)
print(out)

# Output
   A1  A2  A3  A4  B1  B2  B3  B4  A_diff  B_diff
0  10  10  30  75  10  30  10  40     -25      10
1  20  20   0   0  20   0  10  30      40       0
2  30  30  40   0  30  20  20  20     100      50
3  10  40  10  25  40  40  30  10      35     100
```

You can also group columns by position. If you need to iterate over 4 columns each time:

```
df1 = (df.groupby(np.arange(len(df.columns)) // 4, axis=1)
         .apply(difference).add_suffix('_diff'))
```

Comment: Thank you, I ended up using the position-based solution because it felt most resilient.

One additional question I have, is it possible to have the group by position start at a certain spot? I made sure my data frame contained *only* the relevant columns to solve this problem, but I'd like to know for the future.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to convert the columns to a MultiIndex and operate on that:

```py
def difference(df):
    temp = df[:] # avoid a full copy, since we are working only on the columns
    temp.columns = (temp
                   .columns
                   .str
                   .split(r'(\d)', expand=True)
                   .droplevel(-1)
                  )
    result = {f"{label}_diff":  temp.loc(axis=1)[label].iloc(axis=1)[:-1].sum(axis=1) 
                              - temp.loc(axis=1)[label].iloc(axis=1)[-1] 
              for label in temp.columns.get_level_values(0)}
    return df.assign(**result)

df.pipe(difference, ['A', 'B'])
   A1  A2  A3  A4  B1  B2  B3  B4  A_diff  B_diff
0  10  10  30  75  10  30  10  40     -25      10
1  20  20   0   0  20   0  10  30      40       0
2  30  30  40   0  30  20  20  20     100      50
3  10  40  10  25  40  40  30  10      35     100
```

Another option is with a bit of regex:

```py
def difference(df, labels):
    result = {f"{label}_diff":  df.filter(regex=fr"{label}[1-3]").sum(axis=1) 
                              - df.loc(axis=1)[f"{label}4"] 
              for label in labels}
    return df.assign(**result)

df.pipe(difference, ['A', 'B'])
   A1  A2  A3  A4  B1  B2  B3  B4  A_diff  B_diff
0  10  10  30  75  10  30  10  40     -25      10
1  20  20   0   0  20   0  10  30      40       0
2  30  30  40   0  30  20  20  20     100      50
3  10  40  10  25  40  40  30  10      35     100
```

Comment: @Corralien's solution worked for me, but thank you for sharing this — I can see why Multiindex is very useful and I'm happy to learn about it!